# Enable Blank Search Queries to show all products

Tags: magento2.2, catalogsearch

Currently working with Magento 2.2 -- Looking to enable blank searches which retrieve top 20 products, etc. I don't see any settings to enable something like this, anyone know which module the code for that would be in? I think I found it but not sure if it's modifying the advanced search parameters or not.